# Select all rows that ends in 1 hour

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `konkurrencer` with column `slutter`, which datatype is `datetime`.

*How can I select all from that table where the rows "ends in" 1 hour?*

Let's say I have a prize into that table. It ends in 1 hour, therefore it has to output the row. If the row ends in 2 hours it should not output it. Only if 1 hour.

But how?

Comment: select * from konkurrencer where slutter > date("1 hour")

Comment: You may have added this to your question it shows you have made some effort to show.Good you have your answer now please ensure this from next time to show what you have done.Read [FAQ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this query.

> ```
>  SELECT *
>     FROM konkurrencer 
>         WHERE slutter < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
>             AND slutter >= NOW()
> ```

Comment: very happy if you can accept this answer..:)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<?php 
    $time = time() - (60*60); //Gives you last hour
    $sql = "SELECT *
    FROM konkurrencer
    WHERE slutter = $time";
?>
```